# SphinxSearch indextool dumpdict what is the output format?

Tags: sphinx

Executing [`indextool`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/ref-indextool.html):

`indextool --dumpdict myindex`

gives output like this:

```
anymore,1,1,329756
baltimore,3,5,153685
```

Obviously the first column is the keyword, what are the other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, isn't there a header row :)

```
keyword,docs,hits,offset
```

(I suppose offset, but might not be self explanatory. AFAIK, just the offset within the doclist file. Sphinx uses that processing queries, the dict is a quick lookup table. probably of little use to external users, and can be ignored)